# Error 405 (method not allowed) using ajax method post laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

There is an ajax script to remove comments under posts. When I click the delete button, I get a 405 error.
The console displays this: `DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/id2/post/582 405 (Method Not Allowed)`, although the method is different url

My route `Route::delete('/id{id}/post/{postId}/comment/{commentId}/delete', 'CommentController@deleteComment')->name('deleteComment');`

And script

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click","#deleteComment",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('deleteComment', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id, 'commentId' => $comment->id])}}",
            type: "DELETE",
            data: {_token: token, id: id},
            success: function() {
                $("div.commentPost[data-id="+id+"]").remove();
            },
        });
    });
});
```

I need that when I press delete, the record disappears, but it does not disappear. To make the entry disappear, you need to reload the page

Comment: do you return something like this: `return response()->json($response);` in your controller?

Comment: are you sure `id{id}` works to determine the route parameter? If it doesn't you might be getting conflicts

Comment: `Route::delete('/id{id}/post/{postId}/comment/{commentId}/delete',` it would be `Route::delete('/id/{id}/post/{postId}/comment/{commentId}/delete',`??? May be you misspelled, `/id{id}` wont work,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood Laravel actually uses POST request within an _method as parameter when you perform destroy operation, so your JavaScript section should looks like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click","#deleteComment",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('deleteComment', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id, 'commentId' => $comment->id])}}",
            type: "POST",
            data: {_token: token, id: id, _method: 'DELETE'},
            success: function() {
                $("div.commentPost[data-id="+id+"]").remove();
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this solved the problem. Under the hood laravel sends the `_method` hidden entry because `<form>` HTML elements cannot use methods other than `POST` or `GET`. However `$.ajax` **can** use these methods so Laravel should be able to correctly respond to `DELETE` http requests. Can you please provide with a playsible explanation as to why `post` with `_method` works where the method directly doesn't work?

Comment: Alright, here is the thing, Apache or most of the server doesn't allow DELETE requests. You will need to update your server configuration to respond to the DELETE request. It is not an issue related to laravel.  use .htaccess and put "<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
  Allow from all
</Limit>"

Comment: Ok, that's theoretically possible, though I would like to point out that by default Apache does allow DELETE. It's quite uncommon for anyone to manage to configure it to not allow DELETE

Comment: That's why I didn't mention in my answer about Apache configuration. Anyhow the point should be clear. Happy coding.